# run nodejs server from Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

i need to run nodejs from /home/app/frontend that never stop
what is the nohup command ?

RUN cd pax && mv frontend /home/app
RUN cd pax && mv backend  /home/app

RUN cd /home/app/frontend
RUN npm run build
RUN nohup node /usr/local/bin/serve -s build

Comment: I find hard understanding your question, but why would you anyway want to run node on the frontend, if that's what you are asking?

Comment: You don't really need `nohup` in a docker container. Try to explain what is going wrong with your approach